# Getting a value from controller extension to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, extension

I've been wondering about this alot.  I have a VF page that has a StandardController for Contact and a custom extension that handles an external webservice call.  This extension class contains a string value that the web service call sets and then I need to pass that value to the VF page for display.  This value is not bound to any field in SF but is rather just a string value. I'm trying to use actionFunction to do this, since it seems easier than using JS Remoting (my JS callback function skill level is not high)

VF Page:

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Contact" extensions="CallStatus">


<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="gomob"  action="{!GetCallStatus}" reRender="amount"/>
<div id="black">


<apex:outputpanel id="amount">
            <apex:outputText value="Get Status!: {!amount}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                action="{! GetCallStatus}" 
                                rerender="amount" status="whileStatus"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:actionStatus id="whileStatus" 
                           startText=" (fetching...)" 
                           stopText=" (done)"/>

</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My extension class:

```
global class CallStatus {

    private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public WS_GoMobileStatus(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.controller = controller;
    }

    global String kId { get; set; }
    transient String amount {get; set;}
    Contact con;

    public CallStatus(){


    }

    Public String GetCallStatus(){
    String conId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    con = [SELECT Id,kid__c from Contact where Id =:conId LIMIT 1];
    ktId = con.kid__c;

        String endp = 'ENDPOINT_URL?action=GetCallStatus&kid=';


         HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
         req.setMethod('GET');
         req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
         req.setHeader('User-Agent', 'force.com');
         req.setEndpoint(endp+=ktId);
```

---

```
         Http http = new Http();
         System.HTTPResponse res = new System.HTTPResponse();

          try {

        //Execute web service call here     
        res = http.send(req);       



        //Helpful debug messages
        System.debug(res.toString());
        System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());

} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    //Exception handling goes here....
}       

        amount = res.getBody();
        return amount;


    }
}
```

Is my use of the transient keyword wrong here?  When I refer the {!amount} in the VF page, I get the error 
   `Error: Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.amount`

Is t not possible to have the extension class return the String value to the VF page?

Comment: Contact standard controller does not have an attribute called an 'amount'. Create an getter method in the extension and use it as a variable in pageblock table or some other structure where you would need the value...Might be a wrapper class in the extension will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your variable as -

```
 transient global String amount {get; set;}
OR 
transient public String amount {get; set;}
```

By default, a method or variable is visible only to the Apex code within the defining class.
If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.